# How to keep one instance of the database using express

Tags: node.js, database, express, instance, tedious

I am using express along with sequelize to create a REST API. I want to keep just one instance of my database and use it in all the routes I may create. My first thought was to create the instance as soon as the app runs. Something like this.

```
const express = require('express')
const databaseService = require( './services/database')
const config = require( './config')

const userRoute = require( './routes/user')

const app = express()

databaseService.connect(config.db_options).then(
    connectionInstance => {
        app.use('user', userRoute(connectionInstance))
        app.listen(3000)
    }
)
```

I have not seen something like that so I believe it's not a good approach.

Any ideas ?

Comment: In my opinion, you should only start a connection/instance when you need it. Connection can timeout/drop when there's an sql error, when that happen your whole application will be down. Furthermore it removes the ability of sql transactions.

Comment: If your service is mainly handling db I/O, then opening a persistent connection on startup should be just fine. If I/O is just an incidental part of it, consider breaking it out as a separate microservice.

Answer (score 7):

A strategy that I use extensively in several production applications to great success is to define the database connection logic in a single file similar to the following:

**database.js**

```
const dbClient = require('some-db-client')
let db

module.exports.connectDB = async () => {
  const client = await dbClient.connect(<DB_URL>)

  db = client.db()
}

module.exports.getDB = () => {
  return db
}
```

Obviously, the connection logic would need to be more complex then what I have defined above, but you can get the idea that you would connect to your database using whichever database client library that you choose and save a reference to that single instance of your database. Then, wherever you need to interface with your database, you can call the `getDB` function. But first, you would need to make a call to your `connectDB` function from your server application entry file.

**server.js**

```
async function run() {
  const db = require('./database')
  await db.connectDB()

  const app = require('express')()
  const routes = require('./routes')

  app.use('/', routes)

  app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('App server listening to port 3000')
  })
}
```

You would make the call to initialize your database connection in the server application entry file before initializing `express`. Afterwards, any place in your application that needs access to the database can simple call the `getDB()` function and use the returned database object as necessary from there. This does not require overly complicated connection open and close logic and saves on the overhead of constantly opening and closing connections whenever you want to access the database by maintaining just a single database connection that can be used anywhere.

Comment: How would you call getDB?. Would you need export and pass it along?.

Comment: Correct, you just need to export those two functions. I did not include the export in my code initially because I wanted to leave it up to your export style preference, but I have added the export part to my code above now for clarity.